# Is it possible to completely erase an answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I want this deleted answer to be completely erased:

https://history.stackexchange.com/a/10002/466

Is it possible?

Comment: It seems to me that deleted answers are removed after a time, but I'm not 100% sure. This I assume is so that you have the opportunity to fix the answer and undelete it. I also think you need a certain reputation to be able to see them.

Comment: Deleted answers are never actually completely erased from the system unless an SE employee does so.

Comment: I don't see it at all - but I have much less points.

Comment: @Voitcus You aren't far away from being able to see deleted posts: http://history.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: Why would you want to completely erase the answer? Deletion already returned all the rep points you would have lost from down-votes.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange employees occasionally purge post revisions that contain sensitive information (passwords, credit card numbers, etc), so it's certainly possible.

You could try contacting Stack Exchange directly (through the ["contact us" link](https://history.stackexchange.com/contact) in the footer), but since there's no sensitive information in your answer, I wouldn't be surprised if they declined your request.